# run only downstream tasks not the current task - airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have an `Airflow` DAG which as one `upstream` task and around 40 `downstream` tasks from that one `upstream` (like 1 to 40 mapping). The `upstream` one finished successfully and for some reason I had to stop the `downstream` tasks. Now I want to execute all of them. Is there a way to do it by just executing one command (instead of clearing each individual downstream)?
Doesn't matter if it is from the web UI or from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-execute all of the downstream tasks at the same time, click the 1 upstream task in the DAG UI and bring up it's Task UI. Press "Downstream", "Clear", and confirm you want to clear all tasks selected. Once that has been executed, mark the 1 upstream task as successful. All downstream tasks will then forget their previous state and re-execute.